# Use a Linux Computer as a USB Coupler

Tags: linux, usb, debian

**I am on debian and:**

1. I have a USB controller hooked up to a USB port on my PC (**Device 1**).
2. I have a male to male USB cord hooked up to another port on the PC that connects to **Device 2**. (it is a "bridging" usb cord, and has the chip for it)
3. I want to make them connect to each other as if they were one cord, so neither device knows that there is a computer in the middle.
   This would be called a 'Coupler', except that I am using a PC as a coupler.
   Here is a (really bad) diagram I made:
   [image: coupler diagram]

**What I have done:**

I have been able to connect the two devices independently of each other and sniff the results for when they fail to connect. The devices don't send a large volume of data back and forth.

Maybe there is some kind of command tool that I could use, for example (psudocode):

```
$ couple-usb-ports PORT1 PORT2
```

Comment: I was pretty tired when I wrote this post, please ask for any clarification if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel here.

You might consider looking at this link instead.

http://dan3lmi.blogspot.com/2012/10/sniffing-usb-traffic-different.html

Specifically this.

Windows: You cannot directly capture raw USB traffic on Windows with Wireshark/WinPcap, but it is possible to capture and debug USB traffic on a virtual Windows machine under Oracle Virtual Box.

Comment: I am on debian though, where it is possible (I've done it). ;-)

Comment: Also I already know how to sniff traffic from a direct USB connection to the pc (which can be found in your link). I am trying to take that traffic and output it into another USB port. It is essentially a coupler that sniffs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a simple PC as transparent USB sniffer without extra (expensive) hardware. An USB bus has always *one* host (and one or more devices), and the PC can only be the host. This is a hardware limitation.

But you can [capture USB](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB#Windows) data in a Windows machine using Wireshark and [USBPcap](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/), eliminating the need for the middle box in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

As this post is tagged Linux, I suppose the controller PC is a Linux machine. Instead of connecting USB ports with a male-male connector, which is all kinds of bad (you are connecting the 5V lines of both machine with each other!), just run Wireshark in the controller PC.

There might be a little work to be done previously, as you have to enable Wireshark for USB monitoring (Particularly in Debian, this is disabled by default), and you might have to install a small driver to enable the monitoring. Have a look at [this page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) for more information.

Once you get it working, Wireshark is an excellent tool for this!

Comment: "Instead of connecting USB ports with a male-male connector, which is all kinds of bad (you are connecting the 5V lines of both machine with each other!)"